# whenever I try to run my project I keep getting the development server returned http response code 500 for url in react native --SOLVED

Tags: reactjs, react-native

this problem occurred after deploying sanity to my project(I don't know if it's the source of the problem but just wanted to share it.)
[This is what I see in the emulator]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/otbGz.png)
and the following is what appears in the terminal:

```
Error: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
    at setModule (/home/faisalmwy/development/react-native/food-delivery/node_modules/metro-file-map/src/index.js:553:17)
    at workerReply (/home/faisalmwy/development/react-native/food-delivery/node_modules/metro-file-map/src/index.js:624:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 27260)
    at /home/faisalmwy/development/react-native/food-delivery/node_modules/metro-file-map/src/index.js:395:22
    at DependencyGraph.ready (/home/faisalmwy/development/react-native/food-delivery/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:94:5)
    at Bundler.ready (/home/faisalmwy/development/react-native/food-delivery/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:75:5)
    at IncrementalBundler.ready (/home/faisalmwy/development/react-native/food-delivery/node_modules/metro/src/IncrementalBundler.js:327:5)
    at Server.ready (/home/faisalmwy/development/react-native/food-delivery/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1247:5)
```

I've searched for this problem before, some said to delete the `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`, but it didn't work. others said to reinstall npm altogether. that didn't work also. I also tried running the app on a different local host than usual, since sometimes I and a friend of mine connect at the same time.

I've solved the problem, I typed the answer in the answers section

Thanks for helping ❤.

Comment: what does the console say? "Please check the console for more info"

Comment: doesn't the console mean the terminal? that's what I understood.

Comment: I think there can be differentmore info in the browser console sometimes: https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.62/debugging (see remote JS debugging)

Comment: it states that there are two `Package.json` files in the project, which are the project's file, and sanity's. I think the solution would be to use yarn for the project, and npm for sanity. I actually have tried replacing npm with yarn but it didn't work at all, now I'll try to create a new project with yarn and transfer all the file and see what happens.

Comment: i have no idea what sanity is ;)

Comment: sanity is a tool that replaces back-end for me, I've solved the problem, I'll explain further in the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to stop the application and do the below process:

- `cd android` and `gradlew clean`
- remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
- run `npm i`
- also remove application from simulator or from your device
- rerun application

Comment: truly sorry for the late response. I've tried removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` then running `npm i`. I've also tried deleting the emulator I used.. but for the `gradlew clean`,  in the project I have there is no android file.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM:
the problem was having two `package-lock.json` files. since my project has the sanity file which contains `package-lock.json` as well.

SOLUTION: I've solved the problem By changing from npm to yarn, I tried to convert the project from npm to yarn, but that didn't work. So I had to create a new yarn project then I transferred all the files I needed from the old project, then added the packages using yarn.

I imagine this problem wouldn't happen only with sanity, but with any case where there are two package-lock.json files.

Comment: Always choose the answer that best solves the problem, even if you came up with it yourself.